# Best Way To Read Logs Written By Zend\Log

Tags: zend-framework2

What is a best way to read and analyse logs written by Zend\Log? For example, this is what I have:

```
2013-04-24T11:00:08+00:00 INFO (6): {"foo":"bar"}
2013-04-24T13:02:53+00:00 INFO (6): {"hello":"world"}
```

I want an elegant way to iterate over logs like this:

```
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addReader(new \Zend\Log\Reader\File('./data/logs/mylog'));
foreach ($logger->read() as $dateTimeObject => $jsonObject) {
    /// analyse logged json object
}
```

Wouldn't it be a good idea to also support Reader classes for Zend\Log, not just Writers?

Comment: YAGNI :) I mean logs are mostly(!) used for error logging. The time when you actually take a look into logs is for when something fishy has happened. Since writing logs is so subjective (i.e.: the format), it's difficult to actually give out readers.

Comment: @Sam There are uses for logs apart from error logging. Reporting, data mining, testing (for example testing sending of emails with Behat). I think it would be useful to have at least one basic Reader class for Zend\Log.

Comment: @RichardKnop log files being so varied, it's not surprising there's not a one-size-fits-most solution.  Given the format you specify, you should be able to write your own pretty simply - just implement the \Iterator interface so you can use foreach() on it.